# WebApi: how to pass state from filter to controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am pulling some user data in action filter, and could use some of that data in a controller's action, but not exactly sure how to pass data from a filter to a controller.
In MVC I'd probably use session or HttpContext.Items, but it's not available in web api. Another option is to use ThreadStatic, but I think there has to be a better solution?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `Request.Properties` dictionary to do that.

In the filter:

```
MyType myObject = //initialize from somwhere
actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("mykey", myObject);
```

And then you can retrieve it in the controller:

```
object myObject;
Request.Properties.TryGetValue("mykey", out myObject);
//cast to MyType
```

The advantage of this approach is that the current request instance is available everywhere in the Web API pipeline, so you can access this object i.e. in the Formatter or MessageHandler too.

Comment: My Request object doesn't have Properties, only Params. Is there a difference? And it doesn't exist in directly within the filterContext, but in filterContext.HttpContext.

Comment: then you are dealing with MVC filter not Web API filter - the first are used with ASP.NET MVC pipeline and are members of system.web.mvc, while the latter are used with ASP.NET Web API pipeline and are members of system.web.http. Do not confuse them, they are different components

Comment: @FilipW, how can we access HttpRequestMessage in services i.e custom service as dependency injection with autofac ?