# How to keep alive a variable among a class inherit from ApiController and other one inherit from ExceptionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, action-filter, exceptionfilterattribute

I have my controller `SomeController` and its inherited from `ApiController`, also, I have an `ActionFilter`:

**FilterConfig**

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new LogExceptionFilterAttribute());
        }
    }
```

**ErrorLogService**

```
public static class ErrorLogService
    {
        public static void LogError(Exception ex, string metodo, string clase)
        {
            Utilidades.EnviarErrorHTTP(ex, null, metodo, clase);
        }
    }
```

**LogExceptionFilterAttribute**

```
public class LogExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
        {            
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

Well, the session is handled by the `ApiController` and in my `SomeController` I can use it like:

`var session = TokenUser;`

But, there nothing in my `ErrorLogService` to invoke the function to know the token.

Is there a way to share this variable if it is different in each session?
(`TokenUser` is an object).

Comment: Your question is unclear - where is `TokenUser` instantiated? What does it contain? Please put the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Usually `Request.Properties` dictionary is used for passing state between different layers of ASP.NET Web Api. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059161/webapi-how-to-pass-state-from-filter-to-controller) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

In the **Global.asax** you must add the next code:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
```

And now, you are available to use `Session`:

```
var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
session["token"] = sesion;
```

And the variable `session` would persist in the application.