# Best way to keep user configuration in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services, authentication

I'm working on a project with Web API 2 and I'm trying to find the best way to save the user configuration in memory.

Each user has a particular configuration (timezone, location, language, its company information, and many more information), so I'm trying to implement a way to query this information at first login and save it to memory or something. So this information is frequently used by many operations and I don't want to slow down the application performance by querying all that info each time I need it.

So, the first plan was to implement a Static clas with this information, but I don't know if it's the best approach.

Can someone suggest the best way to implement this on a Web API 2?

Comment: If your services are intended to be RESTful (per the `rest` tag), adding server-side session state breaks that.

Comment: You could use `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. E.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907961/1220550)

Comment: you can use redis cache

Comment: In memory hosting will be helpful in this case: https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/

Comment: Depending on the amount of data, you might find claims-based authentication suitable. The data would be encoded in a token that is part of each API request.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all additional information in claims identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the information in session:

Try with:
In the **Global.asax** you must add the next code:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

And now, you are available to use Session in your controllers or classes:

```
var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
session["token"] = "abc";
```

And the variable session would persist in the application and get the `session` values

```
var abc = session["token"].ToString();
```

Reference:
[How to keep alive a variable among a class inherit from ApiController and other one inherit from ExceptionFilterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265780/how-to-keep-alive-a-variable-among-a-class-inherit-from-apicontroller-and-other/49280298#49280298)